# TTTableView within a TTViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, three20

I am using Three20 to add some table views (`TTTableView`). I have a `TTViewController` which adds a `TTTableView` as a subview using:

```
    _signupTableView = [[TTTableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, kScrollViewHeight + kSignupLabelHeight, 320, kTableViewHeight) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
        [_signupTableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

        _signupTableView.delegate = self;
        _signupTableView.dataSource = [TTSectionedDataSource dataSourceWithObjects:
                                                   @"",
                                                   [TTTableTextItem itemWithText:@"Sign Up" URL:@"tt://signupController"],
                                                   nil];
[self.view addSubview:_signupTableView];
```

And all works ok, EXCEPT when the cell is tapped. The cell turns blue, and remains that way. The navigation is never pushed to *tt://signupController*.

Can anyone think of a reason that this is not working??? I found a similar SO question describing the same symptoms, but their issue was with the drag-to-refresh controller, which I am not using.

Any help would be great, I am at a loss here.

Cheers,
Brett

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing any other code it sounds like that you haven't set up the mappings to the different ViewControllers in your App Delegate.  Try adding to your App Delegate:

```
TTURLMap* map = navigator.URLMap;
[map from:@"tt://signupController" toViewController: NSClassFromString(@"SignupController")];
```

Hope this might help you out.

Answer (score 0):

i think this is what you want-

```
-(void)didSelectObject:(id)object atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSLog(@"%d", indexPath.row);
    int i = indexPath.row;

    TTNavigator *navi = [TTNavigator navigator];
    navi.persistenceMode = TTNavigatorPersistenceModeNone;
    TTURLAction *action =  [[[TTURLAction actionWithURLPath:@"tt://signupController"] applyQuery:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:arr forKey:@"stories"]] applyAnimated:YES];
    [navi openURLAction:action];    
}
```

but could you explain me how you made `TTTableView` inside `TTViewController`? i also tried your code above but it crashes with several warnings related to `TTModel`. 
Here is the code i made-

CODE OF .H FILE-

```
@interface Social1 : TTViewController <TTTableViewDataSource, TTTableViewDelegate, TTModelDelegate> {

    TTTableView *_tableview;
}
@property(nonatomic, retain)TTTableView *_tableview;
@end
```

CODE OF .M FILE INSIDE `viewDidLoad`

```
    self._tableview = [[TTTableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, self.view.frame.size.width, 330) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    self._tableview.delegate = self;
    self._tableview.dataSource =
    [TTListDataSource dataSourceWithObjects:
     [TTTableMessageItem itemWithTitle:@"Facebook" 
                               caption:nil
                                  text:kLoremIpsum timestamp:nil
                              imageURL:local_fb URL:@"tt://socialfb"],
     [TTTableMessageItem itemWithTitle:@"Twitter" caption:nil
                                  text:kLoremIpsum timestamp:nil
                              imageURL:local_tw URL:@"http://www.twitter.com/eset"],
     [TTTableMessageItem itemWithTitle:@"YouTube" caption:nil
                                  text:kLoremIpsum timestamp:nil
                              imageURL:local_yt URL:@"tt://videos"],
     [TTTableMessageItem itemWithTitle:@"LinkedIn" caption:nil
                                  text:kLoremIpsum timestamp:nil
                              imageURL:local_li URL:@"http://m.LinkedIn.com/"],
     nil];
    [self.view addSubview:self._tableview];
}
```

Does the code require any other `delegate` methodes?
Please reply.